# Can't use script from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Egg : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    PlayerController playerScript = GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    playerScript.Increment();
}
}
```

It won't let me use the Increment function in the OnTrigger function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable **playerScript** is declared inside the `start` method, there is no variable called **playerScript** in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method.

you should do something like this instead:

```
public class Egg : MonoBehaviour {

    private PlayerController playerScript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
         playerScript = GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        playerScript.Increment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `OnTriggerEnter2D` is really triggered, simply add `Debug.Log("Boom!");` inside `OnTriggerEnter2D`.

Secondly, check if `playerScript` is found. Add this inside OnTriggerEnter2D body

```
Debug.Log("Is playerScript null? "+ (playerScript == null));
```